# Leetcode problem asks for the output to be in List[List[int]] but returns a set without converting into a list

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, set, return-type

This is a solution to a leetcode problem. My problem is with why the output below is acceptable? The problem is expecting List[List[int]] but the "res" that is being returned is a set.

I don't know if python3 has anything to do with this but I couldn't find anything online. Your help is much appreciated.

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        res, dups = set(), set()
        seen = {}
        for i, val1 in enumerate(nums):
            if val1 not in dups:
                dups.add(val1)
                for j, val2 in enumerate(nums[i+1:]):
                    complement = -val1 - val2
                    if complement in seen and seen[complement] == i:
                        res.add(tuple(sorted((val1, val2, complement))))
                    seen[val2] = i
        return res
```

Comment: A set is a valid data structure that can hold a list of lists, because python set doesn't allow duplicate values, this way of solving problem eliminates duplicate answers, and then we can convert the final set to list of list, So at the end, it's correctly returning unique lists of integers as an answer in the form of set, which is acceptable as solution.

Comment: @SeppeWillems hmm you say, "We can convert the final set to list of list" but I don't see that taking place in the above code. All I see is Tuple being sorted and being added to a set?

Comment: indeed, but the set, in this case, gets seen as a List[List[int]]. This should also work `return [list(i) for i in list(res)]` this one seems to be a little faster but takes more memory it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typings in python aren't enforced in any way. You can write

```
def f() -> int:
    return "abc"

f()
```

And everything will work smoothly (you will be warned by some linters like `mypy`, but nothing that stops this from executing)

So there is no problem on your side with the code. But the second question is, what leetcode does to check your answer? Probably they doing something like:

```
for single_list in threeSum(...): # they call your function
    <check if single_list is correct>
```

Notice that it doesn't matter do you returned set, list, tuple or any other iterable - such checker would work for any of them until it contains what's expected.

Comment: That's interesting. I was, of course, aware that typing isn't enforced in Python but I thought/ expected that Leetcode would check the type of the output under the hood. Thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: Notice that such checkers are written by programmers like you and me and... we are usually lazy, so we are choosing the easiest way to achieve the goal ;)
And we produce bugs as well, so you can probably get 100% score for non working program sometimes.